# How to Set default value of empty data of column in copy activity from csv file using azure data factory v2

Tags: default-value, azure-data-factory

I've multiple csv files and multiple tables.
The table name is file name and column name is first row of csv file.

Now I want to add default value of empty string to the sink table.

Consider my scenario,

**employee:**
id int, name varchar, is_active bit NULL

### employee.csv:

id|name|is_active

1|raja|

Now I'm trying to copy the csv data to PostgreSQL table its throwing error.
Expected result is default value if its empty value.

Comment: Could you please show the complete error message? Could you please help me with the source as the sink is PostgreSQL Tables.

Comment: Thanks @IpsitaDash,
Please find the mentioned error below.

Comment: {"Message":"ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '' for column name 'is_active' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'Int16' (precision:0, scale:0). Additional info: Input string was not in a correct format."}

Comment: Note: now the is_active column is smallint

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULLIF in PostgreSQL:

```
NULLIF(argument_1,argument_2);
```

The NULLIF function returns a null value if `argument_1` equals to `argument_2`, otherwise it returns `argument_1`.

This way you can replace NULL value with some other value

If your error is related to Type mismatch then consider typecasting the column first

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @PratikSomaiya, where I need to use NULLIF. Can you please explain

Comment: You need to use it in COPY activity while copying the data from source

In the Source section you will find an option to write a SQL query there you can add the query and use NULLIF for the column for which you need to replace NULL values

Comment: Hi, if you found my response helpful, can you please mark it as an answer so that others in the community will get the benefit if they are facing the same query

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the issue, tried to repro the scenario and here is the following outcome which was successfully copied. You have to use

**Source Dataset:** `employee.csv` from Azure Blob Storage

[image]

**Sink Dataset :** Here, I have used the sink as Azure SQL DB for some limitations but as you have used PostgreSQL is almost similar.

[image]

**Copy Activity Settings:**

Under the `mapping settings` there will be type conversion, where you have to import schema else you can dynamically add
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Alternative** to use `DataFlow` - if you have multiple data fields, you need to use the derived column transformation to generate new columns in your data flow or to modify existing fields.

For more details, refer [Derived column transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column).

You can even refer to this Microsoft Q&A post for more insights: [Copy Task failure because of conversion failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401569/copy-task-failure-because-of-conversion-failure.html)

Comment: Thanks @IspitaDash,

For my scenario is generic, without column mapping I need to copy.

Comment: Because I'm iterating multiple csv files each file is different tables,
header is column name